# Actionscript3: Does variable exist?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, variables, adobe, exists

I'm a little bit new to Actionscript, but I can't figure this one out. I've done a lot of searching on this topic and haven't found a clear answer. I've tried the following solutions that people posted online but none of them work.

All the following *solutions* give the error: *1120: Access of undefined property myVariable*

**Suggestion #1:**

```
try {
     trace(myVariable); }
catch {
     trace("your variable doesn't exist"); }
```

**Suggestion #2:**

```
if (myVariable) {
     trace("your variable exists!!"); }
else {
     trace("it doesn't exist"); }
```

**Suggestion #3:**

```
if ( myVariable == null )
     trace("your variable doesn't exist");
```

**Suggestion #4:**

```
if ( myVariable == undefined )
     trace("your variable doesn't exist");
```

Like I said, I've found many forums posts and stuff online that give the above suggestions saying they will work, but they all seem to be giving me that same *1120: Access of undefined property myVariable* error.

By the way, in case you are wondering why I would need to check if a variable exists or not, I'm planning on passing variables to the SWF in its URL, so I need to make sure the proper variables exist and handle the code properly if they are not passed in.

---

Thanks for the quick reply. Still not really working. The scope of the variable is just on the top/root level of the script. Basically, I start a new flash file, on the first frame I add the following action:

```
// to check for this.myVariable
if ( this.hasOwnProperty( "myVariable" ) ) {
     trace("myVariable exists");
}
else
{
     //Variable doesn't exist, so declare it now
     trace("declaring variable now...");
     var myVariable = "Default Value";
}

trace(myVariable);
```

When I run the flash file, I get this output:

```
myVariable exists
undefined
```

I was expecting this:

```
declaring variable now...
Default Value
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> By the way, in case you are wondering
>   why I would need to check if a
>   variable exists or not, I'm planning
>   on passing variables to the SWF in its
>   URL, so I need to make sure the proper
>   variables exist and handle the code
>   properly if they are not passed in.

Then you are taking the wrong approach. Here's the right way™ to read and validate SWF parameters, along with default value if they don't exist:

```
private function parameter(name:String, defaultValue:String):String
{
        // Get parameter list
    var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(stage.loaderInfo).parameters;

        // Check if parameter exists
    if(paramObj.hasOwnProperty(name) && paramObj[name] != "")
        return paramObj[name];                     
    else
        return defaultValue;
}
```

Warning! Since this relays on the 'stage' property, Use this code either from the Document Class or after `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE`.

Answer (score 12):

LiraNuna's answer is definitely the *right* way to access loader parameters. However, to answer the question of how to check for the existence of variables (for posterity), this is done with the [hasOwnProperty()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/Object.html#hasOwnProperty%28%29) method, which exists on all objects:

```
// to check for this.myVariable
if ( this.hasOwnProperty( "myVariable" ) ) {
    trace("myVariable exists");
} else {
    //Variable doesn't exist, so declare it now
    trace("declaring variable now...");
    this.myVariable = "Default Value";
}

trace( this.myVariable );
```

That should cover your situation. But I don't know of any way to check the existence of a variable the way you're trying to do, by merely making a reference directly to the variable. I believe you must refer to it through its scope.

Answer (score 0):

fenomas is probably most right. (I should probably modify some of my code to use that method). But the method I currently use for classes is:

```
try {
  if(this["myFunction") {
    this["myFunction"]();
  }
catch(e:Error) {}
```

which isn't the most elegant since it does throw exceptions.

My reason for using this sort of code is that we're doing a bit of dynamic coding and abusing  "includes" in flex to write boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

trace(myVariable);

Answer (score 0):

When stage is not available, you may try to extract parameters from root.loaderInfo.parameters.  Take care to check whether each property of the chain is null.

```
if( root != null && root.loaderInfo != null && root.loaderInfo.parameters != null ) {
     myVar = root.loaderInfo.parameters.myVar;
}
```

Comment: `root` will not be available if the DisplayObject is not a part of the display list.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (myVariable === "undefined") {
      trace("variable doesn't exist");
    else
      trace("variable exists");
```

Note the triple comparison operator. It's a little trick I learned from my Javascript days. Also works in AS3 and it's useful for checking if array element exists even if null. Like this:

```
var array:Array = ["zero", 1, null];
if (array[2]) //returns false
if (array[2] !==  "undefined") //returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem recently, and I looked up ways to fix this. However, I've found that when you register the variable like so...

```
var i:int;
```

... that it does not reset the variable if it has already been made. For example, if this is my code on Frame 1:

```
var i:int;
if (i > 0){
    i++;
} else {
    i = 1;
}
```

Then these will be the values of "i" every time flash goes back over the same frame:

```
// First Iteration
trace(i); // 1
// Second Iteration
trace(i); // 2
// Third
trace(i); // 3, etc...
```

It worked in my own project, and it's a LOT less code than the previous answer. I hope it works for you, too.